# Why I can't write a underscore in the table name on python with MySQLdb lib?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to read data from a table but I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dbevent.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor.execute(data)
[...]
    self.description = self._result and self._result.describe() or None
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 1: invalid 
continuation byte
```

The python code is

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="",    
                     user="",        
                     passwd="", 
                     db="modelo_conexion")       
cursor = db.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM "
table = "2017_maq_u02"
data = query + table
cursor.execute(data)

results = cursor.fetchone()

print(results)
db.close()
```

I try with a table name without underscore and works perfectly.

Comment: Your script might not be written in utf8 but in cp152 or Latin...

Comment: @JeanDoux this has nothing to do with the script's encoding.

Comment: @Gonza this has nothing to do with having underscores in your table name. Your database connection is opened with the utf-8 encoding and your table seems to contain non utf-8 data. You have to check your client encoding (checl MySQL doc for this), table encoding and what you really have in your table.  You may want to use the command-line mysql client for inspection.